# Virus from using Scanner class on a URL?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, virus

This may be a silly question but is it possible to get a virus while using the Java class Scanner on a potentially dangerous URL.

```
    URL url = new URL("http://www.VirusInfectedWebsite.com");


    try{

    PrintWriter fw = new PrintWriter("Test.txt", "UTF-8");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(url.openStream());
    while(s.hasNextLine()){
    String line = s.nextLine();
    fw.println(line);
    System.out.println(line);
    }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
    url = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com");
    }
    finally{
    url = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com");
    }

    }
}
}
```

Does using the scanner in this way physically visit the web page or does it just pull information from it.

Comment: `url.openStream()` returns you an `InputStream`, pulling text data from the web-site using http-protocol. There is no known sucurity problems  with that thing. If by visiting web-page you mean visiting it with browser (and executing javascript) - it doesn't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What do you think Virus is?

It is malicious lines of codes than when **executed** may result in output that you may not desire. By your code you are simply reading content of a web site and printing it in your console. That should not affect anything.

Comment: Exactly. The reason why malicious URL may infect your system when you open then /in a browser/ is that the browser interprets the returned data and potentially executes code received from that URL more or less /automatically/.

Answer (score 0):

When we request data from a server, the data received is lines of text (html mostly). A virus code is not a virus until it is executed! So it is safe to use Scanner on any webpage. Displaying text does not mean that you are executing it.

Well, however if you put that text in a file and open using web browser then it will execute! thus activating the virus (in case of malicious website).